# Three JS Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, typeerror

Working on a project where on a button click script fetches a .svg and a .obj. Currently the button finds the .svg and the .obj but then spits out this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Here is the code for the button, all other ThreeJS variables and calls are in the HTML and finish loading before the button is clicked.

```
function item(section, callback){
    var tmp = itemName.split('-');
    var cut = tmp[tmp.length-2];
    var styleNo = tmp[tmp.length-1];
    var path;
    var model;
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    if (_product.svgPathAbsolute) {
        path = itemName + '.svg';
        model = styleCode + '.obj';
    } else {
        path = _product[section].svgPath + _product.name.toLowerCase() + '/' + cut.toLowerCase() + '/' + itemName + '.svg';
        model = _product[section].svgPath + _product.name.toLowerCase() + '/' + cut.toLowerCase() + '/' + styleCode + '.obj';
    }

    loader.load( model, function ( object ) {
            object.traverse(function(node){
                if(node.material){
                    node.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                    node.material = material;
                }
            });
            object.position.y = -100;
            geometry = object;
            scene.add(geometry);
        });

    $.get(path, function (svg) {
        _html[section] = svgToString(svg);
        callback(section);
    });
}
```

Included in HTML

```
<script>
  var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
  var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
  var geometry;
  var material;
  var svg = document.getElementById("svg-holder").querySelector("svg");
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.width = svgSize.width;
  canvas.height = svgSize.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
  manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
    console.log( item, loaded, total );
  };
  var texture;

  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );

  init();
  animate();
  function init() {
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.z = 150;
    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0.9 );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    var directLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0.2 );
    camera.add( directLight );
    scene.add( camera );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
    controls.minPolarAngle = 1.5;
    controls.maxPolarAngle = 1.5;

    var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);

    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData))) );
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: texture
        });
        material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    };



    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:garmentOBJ,antialias:true});
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    //
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
  }
  function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
  }
  function render() {
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: try passing scene into your function, it looks like it scoped in the init function and you don't have access to it. Unless its a global.

Comment: I didn't even realize, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

make the scene object global or bind it to window object like this: `window.scene = scene`.